# Jquery Modal Dialog Having Old Values

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

Below is my simple Jquery Dialog. I have the same class 5 times in the page. I am using Iframe to load another page in Dialog.

For the first time, all the fields are empty. Once I select the values and Open for another dialog, it is showing the old values. How to load page with empty values.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".imgSearch").click(function (e) {
            $("#divSearch").dialog({
                open: function () {
                    $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                    .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                    .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
                },
                title: "Search Employee",
                show: "scale",
                modal: true,
                width: '55%',
                height: 500
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The dialog will contain the same contents it had from the previous with respect to content.  You will need to code to clear out any elements. I would also add a `close` event handler and *destroy* the last instance, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".imgSearch").click(function (e) {

        //Clear elements here.....

        $("#divSearch").dialog({
            close: function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); },
            open: function () {
                $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
            },
            title: "Search Employee",
            show: "scale",
            modal: true,
            width: '55%',
            height: 500
        });
    });
});
```

When you don't destroy you will get the same dialog over and over as well as any closure'd references to objects.  That will result in *weird* behavior.

To clear all the  elements in your div you should do something like before you open the dialog:

```
$('#divName input').val('');
```

To load from IFrame try this:

```
var _dlg = null;   // <- declare this before the $(document).ready(...) code.
```

Use it here:

```
if ( _dlg != null ){
   $(_dlg).dialog('destroy');
}
_dlg = $("#divSearch").load('youriFrame.aspx').dialog({
            close: function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); },
            open: function () {
                $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
            },
            title: "Search Employee",
            show: "scale",
            modal: true,
            width: '55%',
            height: 500
        });
```

Comment: Hello, I destroyed the dialog but still it is showing the old values.

Comment: the old values are there because the inner html contained within the DIV that makes up your dialog has not been changed back to what you want.  You must do that... you only posted the javascript, you should post the HTML that contains the DIV so I could give you better direction.

Comment: Here is the html which is in iframe. Do you want me to post all the html in dialog ?  <div id="divSearch" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
        <iframe id="iSearchEmplyees" src="SearchEmployee.aspx" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width: 100%; height: 99%; border: none; overflow: hidden" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
    </div>

Comment: yes, of you need to.. but YOU MUST CLEAR/SET the values of any element you want before showing the dialog.

Comment: ugh, this is an iframe, i see...  t

Comment: where is the code that reloads the dialog?  you've only shown the startup

Comment: nevermind, i see that it's a clicked event...  i would make sure the destroy happens...  will update answer

Comment: Hello, I posted in the first post that I am loading from Iframe.

Comment: get rid of the iframe inside the `<div>` and try my latest update on my answer.

Comment: Jquery is throwing this error message. Line: 516
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Comment: add the var `var _dlg = null;` part and then use it in the `clicked` event.

Comment: Hello, Please look at this link. I explained my issue in detail. http://forums.asp.net/t/1979701.aspx?Jquery+Modal+Dialog+Having+Old+Values

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem before but it was with bootstraps modals. What I saw to be the problem was that I was using the same instance of my one modal multiple times. You will have to maybe create different ones not reuse one for multiple.

Just going on from my experience.

Comment: I tried to create different instances also but still showing the old values.